# If Element does not exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have around a dozen solutions to this, but none seem to fit what I am trying to do.  The XML file has elements that may not be in the file each time it is posted.

The trick is, the query is dependent upon a question value to get the answer value.  Here is the code:

```
string otherphone = (
    from e in contact.Descendants("DataElement")
    where e.Element("QuestionName").Value == "other_phone"
    select (string)e.Element("Answer").Value
).FirstOrDefault();
otherphone = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherphone)) ? otherphone.Replace("'", "''") : null;
```

Under the "contact" collection, here are many elements named "DataElement", each with its own "QuestionName" and "Answer" elements, so I query to find the one where the element's QuestionName value is "other_phone", then I get the Answer value.  Of course I will need to do this for each value I am seeking.

How can I code this to ignore the DataElement containing QuestionName with value of "other_phone" if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Any` method to check whether or not the elements exists :

```
if(contact.Descendants("DataElement")
     .Any(e => (string)e.Element("QuestionName") == "other_phone"))
{
   var otherPhone =  (string)contact
                   .Descendants("DataElement")
                   .First(e => (string)e.Element("QuestionName") == "other_phone")
                   .Element("Answer");
}
```

Also, don't use `Value` property if you are using *explicit* cast.The point of *explicit* cast is avoid the possible exception if the element wasn't found.If you use both then before the cast, accessing the `Value` property will throw the exception.

Alternatively, you can also just use the `FirstOrDefault` method without `Any`, and perform a null-check:

```
var element =  contact
              .Descendants("DataElement")
              .FirstOrDefault(e => (string)e.Element("QuestionName") == "other_phone");

if(element != null)
{
    var otherPhone = (string)element.Element("Answer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know if `other_phone` exists or not?

```
XElement otherPhone = contact.Descendants("QuestionName")
    .FirstOrDefault(qn => ((string)qn) == "other_phone");

if (otherPhone == null)
{
   // No question with "other_phone"
}
else
{
    string answer = (string)otherPhone.Parent.Element("Answer");
}
```